# Checking if a list contains 1, 2, or 3

Tags: python

The function below always returns false. I want to take a list as input and then find if it contains 1,2 and 3?

```
def arrayCheck(nums):
    # CODE GOES HERE
    if (1 in nums) and (2 in nums) and (3 in nums):
        return True
    else:
        return False

arr = input()  # takes a list as input
x = set(arr)  # coverts it into array
result = arrayCheck(x)
print(result)
```

I want to search the numbers 1,2 and 3 in a user defined list. So I converted the list into a set for having unique elements. Further I have used `in` method to search for the items. The problem is it returns false every time.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice. I'm not sure why someone downvoted the question. It seems fine to me. I guess you could have checked the value of `x` as part of your debugging, but that's not very obvious to a newcomer. In the future you might find it useful to step through your code with a debugger, like [Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html) for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function works, you are inputting wrong data (`arrayCheck([1, 2, 3])` returns `True`).

You can't take a list as input. Converting a string to a set will separate the characters to a set, which isn't what you want (`set("hello") == {'h', 'l', 'o', 'e'}`), so you have to input a list of ints.

Something like this:

```
inp = input().split(",")
inp = [int(i) for i in inp] # Convert all the values to ints
print(arrayCheck(inp))
```

and providing `1,2,3,4` as input will work.

By the way, you can return bools in functions:

```
def arrayCheck(nums):
    return (1 in nums) and (2 in nums) and (3 in nums)
```